# How to change date string to other date string

Tags: c

I have to modify .c program, but i have very limited knowledge of c programming.
How can i change 
input string '3.10.2014'
to output string '2014-10-03' ?

```
char *in = '3.10.2014'
char *out = something(*in)
```

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First change the call to:

```
char date[] = "3.10.2014";
change_date(date);
```

This makes `date` into an array which you can actually modify, as opposed to a string literal which you cannot.

Then write `change_date()`, using e.g. `sscanf()` and `sprintf()`:

```
void change_date(char *s)
{
  int y, m, d;

  if(sscanf(s, "%d.%d.%d", &d, &m, &y) == 3)
  {
    sprintf(s, "%d-%d-%d", y, m, d);
  }
}
```

The above does *not* use `%04d` to format the year, in the hopes of being slighly less likely to break if the available buffer space is too small.

It would be better to also accept a `size_t s_max` argument and use `snprintf()`, and have a return value. I opted for brevity.